# Trying to select 2 union fields as one field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This code doesn't work. It says, "no contact function."

```
SELECT
contact(member.Sname,
member.Ssurname) as tee
FROM
member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `concat` function here.

Comment: thanks for marking this answered.  for future reference, if the error is 'no such function', check the manual again for possible typos or incorrect signature.